# Customize TinyMCE Code Editor

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I use TinyMCE (with react-tinymce moudle on npm). I need to customize the HTML code editor, so that it looks like the one on Wordpress. I think it should be possible as Wordpress use TinyMCE.

What makes the editor on Wordpress comfortable is we don't need to enter `<br>` or `<p>` on code editor. But when we switch to visual mode, it will add `<br>` or `<p>` automatically. That makes the text looks much cleaner and easier to read.

Another question is how to make the code editor not displayed in a popup. The main problem with the popup is it will be closed when we accidentally press esc or the cancel button. In addition, the Wordpress code editor also has a toolbar, while the default TinyMCE code editor is just a textarea on a popup.

Answer (score 0):

The code plugin that comes with TinyMCE places the HTML code is a separate window - there in no configuration option that will allow the code to appear directly in the editor's main window.

If you'd like to submit this as a feature request, TinyMCE has a place for that:

https://community.tinymce.com/communityIdeasHome